# Says Updated Successfully But When I look At The Database It's Not

Tags: php, mysql

Can you guys double check my codes. When I clicked the Update button it told me that the update was successful but when I look at my database nothing changed. I know I'm doing something wrong. Hope you guys help me to figure it out. Thanks.

I am still learning and it's an honor to learn from you guys. Please be nice and use basic terms hehe

```
<html>
<body>

<div>
    <form action="edit.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>" method="post">

              <div>
                <label for="prov">Provinces</label><br>
                <select id="prov"type="text" name="provi1">
                  <option><?php echo $provi; ?></option>
                  <option value="Isabela">Isabela</option>
                  <option value="La Union">La Union</option>
                  <option value="Pangasinan">Pangasinan</option>
                  <option value="Ilocos Sur">Ilocos Sur</option>
                  <option value="Ilocos Norte">Ilocos Norte</option>
                </select>
              </div>

              <div>
                <label>Date</label><br>
                      <input type="date" name="date" value="">
                  </div>

              <div>
                <label>Typhoon Name</label><br>
                      <input type="text" name="typhoon" value="<?php echo $typhoon; ?>">
              </div>

              <div>
                <label>Warning #</label><br>
                      <input type="text" name="warning" value="<?php echo $warning; ?>">
              </div>

              <div>
                <label for="prov">SS Height</label><br>
                <label>2-3 meters
                  <input type="radio" name="meter" value="2-3 Meters"
                  <?php if ($ssh == '2-3 Meters') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>>
                </label>

                <label>1-2 meters
                  <input type="radio" name="meter" value="1-2 Meters"
                  <?php if ($ssh=='1-2 Meters') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>> 
                </label>

                <label>< 1 meter
                  <input type="radio" name="meter" value="< 1 Meter"
                  <?php if ($ssh=='< 1 Meter') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>>
                </label><br>

                <label for="imp">Impacts</label><br>
                  <textarea id="imp" type="text" name="impact1"><?php echo $impact; ?></textarea>

                  <label for="adv" >Advice</label><br>
                  <textarea id="adv" type="text" name="advice1"><?php echo $advice; ?></textarea>
              </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="submit" value="Update" name="update">
                <input type="reset" value="Cancel">
             </div>
    </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For starters, your code is wide open to SQL injection.  Which is not only a security hole but also a very common source of bugs because you're barely in control of the SQL code you're executing.  As part of your debugging, output the actual runtime value of the query you're executing and test that query manually on your database.

Comment: STOP. Any hacker will be able to remove your entire database within 5 seconds. No joke. Google "SQL injection", try again, this time woth safe code, and then ask again. I know the previous commenter said basically the same but you should know it is THAT serious, so I will just repeat.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question however that information is really helpful. Thank you so much! @David and Roemer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix the MySQL injection, or I WILL come and erase your database. (See comments under question).

Then (and only AFTER you fixed that):

You are using id from the $_GET, but for the update your ID comes from $_POST. However, you forgot to put that `<input name='id' value='<?=$edit?>' type='hidden'>` within your form. So there is no `$_POST['id']`, so it only updates all records with an empty id. And says: "Yay, I succesfully updated 0 records!". Hence no error: it was an overwhelming success. ;)

You seem to be confused about the id. There is no need for an `$edit`, an `$id` and an `$u_id` variable. It is all the same id. Your`<FORM ACTION=...` actually puts `?id=` (empty string) behind the URL, since you emptied `$id`.

Comment: Does `<input name='id' value='<?=$edit?>' type='hidden'>` doesn't work for textarea and others? I tried to put it under the form but only the `input` tags are being updated. The other data like advice, impact and etc were gone. @Roemer

Comment: It is just an inout like all the others, only the user doesn’t see it and can’t change it. Put it of course somewhere between the start en end tag of the form. Doesn’t matter much where. Treat it like any other input.

Comment: Do you have any idea why only the one with `<input>` tags are being updated? And it also erased the others data and save only the ones with input tags.

Comment: Since you temoved the php from the question, I cannot see what you are doing. Basically: it updates anything you put in the query, if you take that from $_POST, it has to have a corresponding input. Anything that is in the query, has to has a corresponding valur )i.e. Value from POST]. If some of either of those values are missing, the query will have an empty value and write that in the database. Only write values that are defined.